# How do I create a JSONP from an external JSON feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I have two domains: www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com

I have a plain JSON feed on domain1.

I want to pull the JSON feed from domain1 and put it on a module on domain2.

From what I've read, the way to go about it is by using JSONP but how do you go about doing that? Is there a way to do it with just JQuery/javascript? Or would I have to use server-side code (I'm using Coldfusion). Also could I just use .getJSON and not .ajax (I'm a beginner so I've never used .ajax yet)

**EDIT**
Okay I'm still getting confused. Just adding callback at the end of the url broke it. How could I make it so that instead of a remote path for a feed I am pulling an absolute path where this code is on www.domain2.com but the feed is on www.domain1.com?

```
var feed ="/event/json.tag/tag/sports/";

$.getJSON(feed,function(data) {

   $.each(data.items, function(i,obj) {

       do something here...
   }        

}
```

Comment: How come `feed` is an absolute? also what is your method? `tag`? can't you use query strings?

Comment: I need the feed to be absolute since I'm making a module that will go on domain2 but the feed is hosted on domain1. That is just the way the url for the feed is setup.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP is just a callback function wrapped around a JSON object.
General convention is to have an endpoint that returns JSON, unless a callback parameter is defined on the request, and returns JSONP in that case.

i.e. http://www.domain1.com/api/getStuff might return:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 'fizz': 'buzz'}
```

then http://www.domain1.com/api/getStuff?cb=cb123 should return:

```
cb123({'foo': 'bar', 'fizz': 'buzz'});
```

I don't know ColdFusion, but I assume this example is good: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/3/11/Writing-a-JSONP-service-in-ColdFusion

There's no client-only solution unless somebody else already built JSONP support into the server you're working with...

Answer (score 0):

Reading the jQuery Documentation [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) and [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) will be a good start, anyway there are a lot of good tutorials about jsonp, [this](http://iamzed.com/2008/01/25/using-jquery-and-jsonp-to-get-aim-status/) one for example is a great tutorial:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.oscar.aol.com/presence/get?k=key&amp;f=json&amp;t=aimuser&amp;c=?",
   function(result){
      if (result.response.data.users[0].state == 'online') {
       $("#status").css("background-image", "url('online.jpg')");
      }
   }
);
```

As mention in the website:

> The f parameter tells the service what
>   format to return the results in--JSON
>   in our case. The c parameter specifies
>   the JSON callback to use--this is
>   important!

And in the jQuery documentation:

> If the URL includes the string
>   "callback=?" (or similar, as defined
>   by the server-side API), the request
>   is treated as JSONP instead.

So keep in mind sending a callback and handling the data afterwords will be easy.

EDIT: another good [example](http://insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html).

EDIT2:
When not specifying the callback value, jQuery will assign it for you (from the $.getJSON page) the flickr URL will become:

> http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?**jsoncallback=jsonp1294786450519**&tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json

And the response:

```
jsonp1294786450519({
        "title": "Recent Uploads tagged cat",
        "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/cat/",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2011-01-11T22:47:12Z",
        "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/",
        "items": [
       { .... rest of json
```

So you need to wrap your json with the callback sent from `domain1`

Comment: So the feed would be instead of "/event/json.tag/tag/food" to            "http://www.domain2.com/event/json.tag/tag/food?format=json&jsoncallback=?"

Comment: exactly. between i guess the extra slash after `.com` is by mistake, right?

Comment: But then on domain1 you would need to ensure that the value of `callback` is wrapped around the JSON as such: `callback_value({JSON:""});` and the `content-type` should be: `text/javascript` instead of `text/application-json` If you don't have control of the output from domain1 you'll need to build a wrapper script to pull the data from domain1 on domain2 (php script perhaps) and return it as JSONP or just JSON cause now you're on the same domain.

Comment: Didn't work. I did http://www.domain.com/event?json.tag&tag=food?format=json&jsoncallback=?   but firebug shows that wasn't pulling anything. If I pull remotely it works fine.

Comment: @sholsinger: I guess you mean the other way around since domain2 is the `server` in his case...anyway thanks, gonna update my answer

Answer (score -1):

You could retrieve the JSON 'feed' from domain1 and pass that data as a parameter to your own Javascript function (on domain2) when your request is completed (onComplete / onSuccess).