# $.getJSON is not working with my website

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, getjson

I'm trying to make cross-domain request with $.getJSON to my site, and it's not working: callback function is not calling. I found this simple example:

```
 $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/usejquery.json?callback=?', function(data) { 
  console.log(data); 
 });
```

And it works with twitter, but not with my site. I copied the file is returned, the server response headers from Twitter, and it still not working. I do not know how to debug it and find out what the problem.

Anyone know what can it be?

Comment: What's your site running on? Is it PHP, ASP .Net web forms, ASP .Net MVC, Ruby on Rails? More information about your setup will help a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663135/how-do-i-create-a-jsonp-from-an-external-json-feed/

Answer (score 1):

Do you return [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)? The trick with the `callback` parameter is, that it's not *JSON*, that's returned, but a JavaScript function call with the "JSON" as parameter. Look at the result of the mentioned Twitter API call for an example.

The [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) docs also talk briefly about this (search for dataType and JSONP).

As to why a copy of the Twitter response does not work: The `callback=?` part of the getJSON call will be filled with a *random* function name. jQuery is making up the name as to not collide with any already existing function, and is deleting the function afterwards.